# Generating pages from a JSON file in Next.js app directory

Tags: json, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a JSON file with routes and path for several pages, Is there a way in Next.js app dir to read to this file and generate all the pages that match the JSON file? without creating all the folder manually.
here's an example:
`{path: "object/demo/demo12", name:"demo12"}`

I created all pages manually and I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this.